# How can I pass 2 separate rules to display separate errors in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a form validation with a few rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'is_unique[user.username]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'is_unique[user.email]|valid_email');
```

I am showing the errors via `json_encode()`.

How can I separate `is_unique[]` and `valid_email` to return more specific reporting to the user?

Comment: I suggest you use a callback method for this.

Comment: That is a better idea now that I think about it more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the individual error with `form_error('fieldName')`

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#showing-errors-individually

Note: Your other option is to create a custom callback, https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: How will retrieving the individual errors make him able to set customs error messages?

Comment: I don't believe that was his question. By default CI returns all error messages in one string. He wanted to stratify them if I understood correctly.
To create specific errors, see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, `is_unique` is used to check against current usernames/emails to make sure the user isn't already registered. With that said, you probably want to run a query, such as I have done in another model. A callback was more suitable, however that isn't always the case, so if you do need to call errors individually to parse them into `json_encode()`, Aaron stated that using `form_error('fieldName')` may work. Now I haven't tried this because I opted to go with the former, not the latter. Hopefully this was helpful to whomever is looking for a similar answer.

Comment: How will you use your callback method? Will you manually run the database query to check if the values is unique? Just curious.